# How to avoid Stripe's 'Pay with card' button style to get screwed up with HTML5up's css?

Tags: css, html, button, stripe-payments

I'm using one of html5up.net's templates and when I add a stripe 'Pay by card' button, it's overridden by the css of html5up (see both jsfiddles below). I tried going through the css file and see if there's anything I could change to affect the button's appearance to no avail (the file is absolutely massive and I could use some steering from more experienced heads).

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3rweq2L/) of how the button is supposed to look like (no css loaded)

```
<title>Lalala</title>
<body>
<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
<script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="a public key"
    data-amount="1000"
    data-name="Lalala"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png" 
    data-locale="auto"
    data-zip-code="true"
    data-currency="eur">
  </script>
</form>

</body>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrzjxa8r/) of how it looks like with HTML5up's css, which is the same code as before plus this line:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

My question: Is there any simple way that I can have just the button be exempt from the css that I have loaded for the site? If not, how would you go about accomplishing that? A new class that has default settings in the css file?

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing you should do is use your favorite web browser’s inspector to find which css is applied to your button. It’ll tell you exactly what css rules are applied and where they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line **1897** of your **CSS** is describing styles applied to the buttons.

If you remove line **1923**:

```
height: 3.75em;
```

It will look kind of ok (or just delete whole section from 1897 to 2050 and you will be fine).

Comment: This option messed up the other buttons of my web a bit, but thanks to your answer I realized that a better way to fix this would be to write the following: '.stripe-button-el {height: 1em;}' in the CSS, so it would only affect stripe's button. Thanks a lot for your reply, it showed me the way to this solution. I appreciate it